# Ubuntu doesn't detect Windows when trying to install from USB boot

Tags: dual-boot

I'm attempting to boot Ubuntu from a USB drive, but when I start the installation, it doesn't recognize that I have Windows 7 on my computer already, and thus doesn't let me choose "Install alongside Windows 7." What should I do to make it detect Windows?

Comment: Have you check bios to make sure safe boot is disabled, this will block any other os from using or detecting it.